# Managing mongoid migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, database-migration, rails-migrations

Can someone give me a short introduction to doing DB migrations in Rails using Mongoid? I'm particularly interested in lazy per document migrations. By this, I mean that whenever you read a document from the database, you migrate it to its latest version and save it again.

Has anyone done this sort of thing before? I've come across [mongoid_rails_migrations](https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations), but it doesn't provide any sort of documentation, and although it looks like it does this, I'm not really sure how to use it.

I should point out I'm only conceptually familiar with ActiveRecord migrations.

Comment: I don't think lazy migrations are a good idea. I'd rather take the time to run a massive data update, wait for it to complete, monitor, think about a way to revert if anything goes wrong, and test it first on a database clone. It takes time but it won't leave you with data inconsistency.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to do the entire migration at once, then mongoid_rails_migrations will do what you need. There isn't really much to document, it duplicates the functionality of the standard ActiveRecord migration. You write your migrations, and then you use `rake db:migrate` to apply them and it handles figuring out which ones have and haven't been ran. I can answer further questions if there is something specific you want to know about it.

For lazy migrations, the easiest solution is to use the [after_initialize](http://mongoid.org/docs/callbacks.html) callback. Check if a field matches the old data scheme, and if it does you modify it the object and update it, so for example:

```
class Person
    include Mongoid::Document

    after_initialize :migrate_data

    field :name, :type => String

    def migrate_data
        if !self[:first_name].blank? or !self[:last_name].blank?
            self.set(:name, "#{self[:first_name]} #{self[:last_name]}".strip)
            self.remove_attribute(:first_name)
            self.remove_attribute(:last_name)
        end
    end
end
```

The tradeoffs to keep in mind with the specific approach I gave above:

If you run a request that returns a lot of records, such as `Person.all.each {|p| puts p.name}` and 100 people have the old format, it will immediately run 100 set queries. You could also call `self.name = "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}".strip` instead, but that means your data will only be migrated if the record is saved.

General issues you might have is that any mass queries such as `Person.where(:name => /Foo/).count` will fail until all of the data is migrated. Also if you do `Person.only(:name).first` the migration would fail because you forgot to include the `first_name` and `last_name` fields.

Answer (score 7):

Zachary Anker has explained a lot in his answer.using mongoid_rails_migrations is a good option for migration.

Here are some links with example that will be useful for you to go through and use [mongoid_rails_migrations](https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations)

[Mongoid Migrations using the Mongo Driver](http://pivotallabs.com/mongoid-migrations-using-the-mongo-driver)

[Embedding Mongoid documents and data migrations](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/embedding-mongoid-documents-in-migrations)

Other then this the [Readme](https://github.com/adacosta/mongoid_rails_migrations/blob/master/README.rdoc) is should be enough with this example to implement mongoid migration

Comment: Readme and pivotal links seem outdated/broken.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same need.

Here is what I came up with: https://github.com/nviennot/mongoid_lazy_migration

I would gladly appreciate some feedback